# Use FingerprintService from a custom service

Tags: android, android-service, android-fingerprint-api

### Background

I have a small app where I want to add fingerprint authentication. This authentication is only used to unlock the app.

The important things are:

- The main point of the app is to run in background as a service.
- The user must to be able to unlock the app from anywhere in the system (not just from the activity).
- The user must to touch a notification to start the service, and therefore start the fingerprint authentication.

### Problem

The `FingerprintService` must to be started from a foreground `Activity`. Even if I put the service in foreground with `startForeground()`, the `FingerprintService` emits a warning:

```
01-01 23:22:11.015 1576-1576/system_process W/FingerprintService: Rejecting com.package.myapp ; not in foreground
01-01 23:22:11.015 1576-1576/system_process V/FingerprintService: authenticate(): reject com.package.myapp
```

This only happens if I touch the notification when I'm outside the app, e.g., in the home screen. If I touch it when I am in the app, the authentication works and I'm able to unlock using my fingerprint (because the `Acticity` is focused, in foreground).

### My current code (only the relevant part)

From the `Activity`, display the notification that starts the service:

```
// NofityManager is a factory class that returns a configured Builder
NotificationCompat.Builder builder = NotifyManager.getBuilder(this);
NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
notificationManager.notify(SERVICE_NOTIFICATION_ID, builder.build());
```

When the service is started, put it into foreground and start the fingerprint authentication:

```
@Override
public void onCreate()
{
    NotificationCompat.Builder builder = NotifyManager.getBuilder(this)
        .setContentTitle(getString(R.string.notification_title2))
        .setContentText(getString(R.string.notification_text));

    startForeground(FOREGROUND_NOTIFICATION_ID, builder.build());

    // this is the class that I use to setup the FingerprintService
    // and call authenticate()
    fingerprintValidator = new FingerprintValidator(this);

    if(fingerprintValidator.check(false))
    {
        try
        {
            fingerprintValidator.startService(this);
        }
        catch(RuntimeException ex)
        {
            Log.d(TAG, ex.getLocalizedMessage() + "\n" + ex.getStackTrace().toString());
        }
    }
    else
    {
        // notify the user
    }
}

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId)
{
    return START_STICKY;
}
```

### Question

How can I use the `FingerprintService` from a custom service running in foreground? I know it is possible because I saw another app doing this, so must to be a way.

Comment: found any solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have your notification launch an Activity that runs the fingerprint sensor, then starts your Service.

Comment: Your answer pointed me to the right way. With a little more research I made it work. Thanks!

Comment: what solution you applied?